# How can I change this footer.php code to call a random image on reload?

Tags: footer

This comes from the `footer.php` file of a wordpress theme I would like to modify. I want one of five images to load on refresh instead of `1.jpg` every time.

```
<script type="text/javascript">

<?php

if((is_archive()) || (is_author()) || (is_category()) || (is_home()) || (is_single()) || (is_tag()) || ($posttype == 'post')  ) {
        $name = "news-and-information";
}else{
        $name = $wp_query->post->post_name;
}

?>

$(document).ready(function(){

        var imgPath = '/wp-content/themes/nexus/img/page-headers/<?php echo $name; ?>/1.jpg';

        $('.subheader-wrapper').css('background-image', ('url("'+imgPath+'")'));

});
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

1. That theme should not be using the `$` alias as WordPress loads
   jQuery in ["No Conflict" mode](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script#jQuery_noConflict_Wrappers).
2. I can only assume the theme is loading its own jQuery, which is
   pretty bad form.
3. The theme should really be [registering](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_register_script) and [enqueuing](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_enqueue_script) the
   script properly rather than just shoving code into the footer.

However, all other things equal and if your images are named numerically, then changing this:

```
var imgPath = '/wp-content/themes/nexus/img/page-headers/<?php echo $name; ?>/1.jpg';
```

To this:

```
var imgPath = <?php echo site_url(); ?>/wp-content/themes/nexus/img/page-headers/<?php echo $name; ?>/<?php echo rand(1,5); ?>.jpg';
```

And it should echo images `1.jpg` through `5.jpg` randomly.

Comment: Using hardcoded relative url with pretty permalinks activated chances are image will not found.

Comment: @G.M. : Yep, you are right. It should not be using relative links either.

Answer (score 0):

Easy way. with **no js** at all.

Somewhere in you template there is a html tag, probably a `div`, with class 'subheader-wrapper'.

So, name images numerically as @s_ha_dum says then change your html from

```
<div class="subheader-wrapper" ....
```

in:

```
<?php
if( ! is_singular() || ($posttype == 'post')  ) {
    $name = "news-and-information";
} else {
    global $wp_query;
    $name = $wp_query->post->post_name;
} 
var img = get_template_directory_uri() . '/img/page-headers/' . $name . rand(1,5) . '.jpg';
?>
<div class="subheader-wrapper" style="background-image:url(<?php echo $imgpath; ?>)" ...
```

I've used `get_template_directory_uri()` instead of relative url, like you do, because using hardcoded relative url with pretty permalinks activated chances are image will not found.